# Go Function Types as Interface Values

Tags: go

I have been reading about [function types as interface values](http://jordanorelli.com/post/42369331748/function-types-in-go-golang) in go and I came across an example that I have not been able to figure out. Here it is:

```
type binFunc func(int, int) int

func add(x, y int) int { return x + y }

func (f binFunc) Error() string { return "binFunc error" }

func main() {
    var err error
    err = binFunc(add)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

You can find it on Go Playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Dzwu9Xaqiy).

I understand that you can assign a method to a function type, but I do not understand how `Error()` is being called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs for the fmt package have this to say:

> Except when printed using the verbs `%T` and `%p`, special formatting
>   considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces.
>   In order of application:
>
> ...
>
> If the format (which is implicitly `%v` for `Println` etc.) is valid for a
>   string (`%s %q %v %x %X`), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the `error` interface, the `Error` method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>      formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method `String() string`, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>      formatted as required by the verb (if any).

In other words, `fmt.Println` will attempt to print the string representation of the interface. Since the error interface is satisfied by `binFunc`, it invokes the `Error` method of `binFunc`.

Comment: Ok, I tried to apply this knowledge in [another example](https://play.golang.org/p/rlkkQo31QJ) by  implementing a `String()` method, but i now get an assignment error. How can the `binfunc(add)` be assigned to an `error` type, but not a `string` type?

Comment: @LiamKelly `binFunc` satisfies the `error` interface by implementing an `Error() string` method. Note that the type of `binFunc(add)` is still `main.binFunc` (`fmt.Printf("%T\n", err)` would say as much), not `string`. Because `error` is an interface, and `binFunc` satisfies the interface, you can use `err = binFunc(add)`. If you removed the `Error` method and left the `String` method, you'd receive a compilation error because `binFunc` and `error` are no longer compatible types since `binFunc` does not implement the `Error` method. Try `var str fmt.Stringer` instead of `string` ;)

Comment: @LiamKelly, Rightly as @user539810 pointed!. And  the fact that you cannot assign  `binFunc(add)` to a 'string' type is simply because binFunc DOES NOT implement a `string` interface (as there is no such interface in both the fmt package or the universe block). `string` is just a type, not an interface, and having any given type implementing `String() string` DOES NOT make that type a `string`. It makes it a `Stringer` because that what the actual interface is: `Stringer`. So if you want your 2nd example to compile and run, just change the line `var str string` to `var str fmt.Stringer`.